'str' object is not callable　のエラーが生じる
seleniumを使ってPythonでスクレイピングをしたいのですが、iframeを使用しているサイトからうまく情報を取れません。
下記のサイト様を参考に、iframeが使用されている場合、目的のフレームに移動しないといけないことはわかったのですが
https://dse-souken.com/2021/05/12/technology/#iframe
CSS_SELECTORなどを試したものの、目的のフレームに移動することができず
まずは、目的のページ内にいくつiframeが有るか調べて
driver.switchTo().frame(0)
というような格好で、目的のフレームにスイッチできないか？と考えたのですが
下記コードを実行した結果
framecnt = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME('iframe')).count()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
となってしまいます。
アドバイス頂けないでしょうか。
（下記コードのurlは便宜上Yahooとしました。）
import selenium
from selenium import  webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://www.yahoo.co.jp/"
driver.get(url)

framecnt = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME('iframe')).count()

print(framecnt)

ご指摘の通り
framecnt = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe').count()

というように変更しました。 'str' object is not callable
に対しては解決しましたが、今度は下記のエラーとなってしまいました。
framecnt = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe').count()
TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

どうやら、countは引数が必要なようです。lenも試そうとしたのですが、lenはリストオブジェクトには使えないようです。
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'len'

framecntの中身は
List[WebElemet]となっております。
このListの中身がいくつあるかを知る、良いメソッドが有ればご教示頂けないでしょうか。
※追記
下記にコメントした通り、解決いたしました。
一応自己解決した、Listの中身を数える方法ですが、非常に初歩的な間違いをしておりました。
framecnt = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')
l = len(framecnt)
print (l)

で数えられました。

XY問題かもしれませんね。そのエラーについて悩むよりも、iframeについてはこちらのページの内容が参考になるのでは？ IFrame と Frame の操作, Python Selenium iframe get element, How to locate an element inside this iframe with selenium?

ご指摘の通り、まさにXY問題でした。狭い知見の中で、「複数要素（Elements）を拾って、その中から目的の要素（Element）を探そう」としておりました。根本的にずれておりました。目的のサイトでは目的のiframeにIDが付いておりましたので、ご紹介頂いたサイトを参考に、目的のiframeをElemetとして取得し、driver.switch_to.frame(取得したエレメント)という形で、目的のフレームに移動して、欲しい情報を取得することができました。ありがとうございました。

解決した場合には質問の本文に追記してしまうのではなく、個別の回答として投稿してください。

本サイトは初めての利用でしたので、ルールがわからず申し訳ございません。今後、自身の質問であっても、自己解決した場合、「質問に回答する」より、解決策を投稿するようにいたします。ご教示ありがとうございます。

driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME('iframe'))ではなくdriver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')ではないでしょうか？
Locating Elements by Tag Name

ご指摘の通りでした。

ありがとうございました。追加で疑問点が出たので、質問を追記いたしました。ご確認頂けますと幸いです。
